# Abrir intent de uma listview

Tags: android

Possuo uma lista de clientes. Gostaria de quando clicasse em um cliente ele abrisse uma nova intent.
Mas fiz alguma coisa errada.
Segue os códigos:

```
 list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ClienteActivity.this, DetalhesCatalogo.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

}
```

Quando rodo ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
09-16 13:13:25.047 1532-1532/com.example.jnior.decorus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jnior.decorus, PID: 1532
    *java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ClienteActivity}: 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead*
```

Comment: Já tá no erro:

Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

Não chame setOnClickListener.
Chama setOnItemClickListener.

Comment: Mas ai tenho que mudar o código, pois se colocar setOnItemClickListener ele dá erro.

Comment: olha ali embaixo a reposta

Comment: é só dar listView.setOnItem (e apertar enter que o android studio auto-completa. depois é só colocar o intent no meio do click)

Comment: Fechou cara. Obrigado. ABS.

Comment: marca como certo. agradeço.

Answer (score 4):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ClienteActivity.this, DetalhesCatalogo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**setOnItemClickListener** ao invés de setOnClickListener